# How to get Tornado Server up and running on Snow Leopard

Tags: tornado

I'm fairly new to osx.  Right out of the box, what are the steps to getting [Tornado Server](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) up and running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Tornado: first, get Apple's XCode (it's probably on your OS installation DVD, or get the latest from [ADC](http://developer.apple.com/) after signing up for free to Apple's Developers Network) and install it.

Then, follow all the simple steps at [the Tornado site](http://www.tornadoweb.org/), i.e.:

- download [the tarball](http://www.tornadoweb.org/static/tornado-0.2.tar.gz)
- open a Terminal.App (Application/Utilities) and cd to the directory where you downloaded the tarball
- tar xvzf tornado-0.2.tar.gz
- cd tornado-0.2
- python setup.py build
- sudo python setup.py install

Optionally also `sudo easy_install setuptools pycurl==7.16.2.1 simplejson` to get all the features of Tornado, as the Tornado site's instructions also mention.

For lighttpd: please open a different question -- that's fundamental SO etiquette.  One question per question is by far best: how would anybody else guess from your question's title that answers also contain information about lighttpd, or other different tools yet?!

Comment: To this I would add: you'll want to install the optional python  dependencies -- gevent and greenlet. Use pip to install these, after installing Xcode (both of them use a C wrapper around kqueue that has to be compiled) if you can.